# Azure Pipelines PowerShell task -- Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have been at this for hours. Hoping someone can help.

I have a variable called "dev-env" in Azure Key Vaults. It is the contents of an appsettings.json file for a .NET environment. I want to write this variable to a file in the pipeline. That's it.

*By the way, yes, I know this is a bit of a hacky solution but it is stop-gap until we can find the time to incorporate key vaults properly into the Startup.cs file and set up the correct permissions.*

Right now, my Azure Pipelines task looks like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Create app settings json files for environments"
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      $(dev_env) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\my-target-folder\appsettings.Development.json
```

However, I get continually getting the error in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have tried escaping the double-quotes(") and colons(:) with backtick(`) and backslash(\) in almost every combination. I have tried wrapping the whole thing in single quotes in both the secret value itself and in the script. I have also tried changing the Content Type on the secret value to "application/json" with no change.

I am able to get the task to work when I add the json as a pipeline variable (not AKV secret) and wrap it all in single quotes (in the actual variable value, not in the script). However, when I do the exact same thing in Azure Key Vaults, it kicks back this error again.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Snippet of my json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing convertTo-Json on the secret value? Don't you want to just write that value to your appSettings.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use macro syntax in-line in your scripts -- it's directly inserting the string into your script. So the entire, unescaped JSON file, including newlines, is being inject into the script. Use an env block to pass the value into the script as an environment variable.

i.e.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Create app settings json files for environments"
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      $env:dev_env | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\my-target-folder\appsettings.Development.json
  env: 
    dev_env: $(dev_env)
```